# Aggregation middleware on mongoose causes it to return empty array when $group stage is used

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB schema for adding posts for my social media website. It has a isDeleted field which shows whether the post is deleted by the user or not. Since I don't want the deleted documents to show up in any queries I added a middleware function in mongoose to filter out the deleted files. But after adding the middleware for aggregation operation, if I add a group stage on aggregation operation it is returning empty array.

```
postSchema.pre("find", function () {
  this.where({ isDeleted: false })
})
postSchema.pre("aggregate", function () {
  this.match({ isDeleted: false })
})
postSchema.pre("findOne", function () {
  this.where({ isDeleted: false })
})
postSchema.pre("findOne", function () {
  this.where({ isDeleted: false })
})
```

I have added the following middlewares in mongoose to remove deleted posts from the returned items. It works fine on normal querying

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'createdAt': {
        '$gte': new Date('Mon, 01 May 2023 00:00:00 GMT'), 
        '$lt': new Date('Thu, 01 Jun 2023 00:00:00 GMT')
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        '$dayOfYear': '$createdAt'
      }, 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The above code is used to query the number of post made in each day of a specific month. This code works fine when used in mongoDBcompass. But when it is used in my node js application it was returning empty array. But when I remove the group stage it returns some documents.

Then I commented out the

```
postSchema.pre("aggregate", function () {
  this.match({ isDeleted: false })
})
```

line inside my schema. Now it works fine. But when I add the above middleware it is again returning empty array when I try to group the documents. Eventhough none of the documents have the isDeleted field set to true.

Comment: Your condition `isDeleted` false should be part of the individual queries, rather than hooks. Hooks are for the purposes of validation, computation etc. not filtering